# how to set context values in serializer fields in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have these models

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Visit(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        'Patient',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        'doctor.Doctor',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail = models.TextField()
```

And this serializer:

```
class VisitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Visit
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I queried patient and doctor from db in views and want to send them to serializer:

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def add_visit_view(request, doctor_pk):
    try:
        patient = Token.objects.get(key=request.auth.key).user
        doctor = Doctor.objects.get(pk=doctor_pk)
    except Patient.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(data={'error': 'patient does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Doctor.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(data={'error': 'doctor does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    user = request.user
    if patient != user:
        return Response({'error': 'user and patient do not match'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    context = {
        'doctor': doctor,
        'patient': patient
    }
    serializer = VisitSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
    data = {}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        patient = serializer.save()
        data['message'] = 'visit added successfully'
    else:
        data = serializer.errors

    return Response(data)
```

I know I have to send extra data using context field but how to set them in serializer
I overwrited create method like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
            visit = Visit(
                patient=self.context['patient'],
                doctor=self.context['doctor'],
                date=self.validated_data['date'],
                time=self.validated_data['time'],
                title=self.validated_data['title'],
                detail=self.validated_data['detail']
            )
            visit.save()
            return visit
```

But when I send request it says doctor and patient field is still required
what should I do?

Comment: From your code, i think you have a misconception of how `view` and `ModelSerializer` work. I've been like that too.

Please read the docs [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

In your case, data to be validated by `VisitSerializer` not from context, but from `request.data` that you passing into serializer class. Make sure you send the data in palyload request.

Comment: Also, one of the functions of the `serializer` is data validation. So, you can move all your validation data like patient, doctor, etc. to your `VisitSerializer`, not in your `view`.  The View  just for logic flow code.